# Is there an iPhone app for cross validated?

Tags: feature-request

Is there an iPhone app for cross validated? This would be pretty awesome, but I think there's no such thing...

Comment: See [StackApps](http://stackapps.com/search?q=iphone), [a question on apple.SE](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12417/what-different-stack-exchange-apps-exist-for-ios/) and [another](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46831/what-different-stack-exchange-apps-are-available-for-the-ipad).

Answer (score 6):

Aside from the excellent user-created apps cardinal linked to, the Stack Exchange team is currently developing mobile apps for the whole network on Android and iOS. The Android app [is in alpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190200/help-us-test-the-alpha-version-of-our-android-app), and beta is near on the horizon. The iOS app is a few steps behind, but it is nearing its alpha testing period. There will be an announcement on MSO when the iOS app is ready for people to sign up to alpha test.